# Cannot resolve Ip address using hostname in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, hostname, local-network

I've been working on project that uses the Hostname of the device connected to a local network and resolve it into ip address.But the problem is android cannot resolve the hostname of the device connected to the same local network

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread( ()->{
            try {
                System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("LAPJA").getHostAddress());.
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot find the specified host");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```

output:

```
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "LAPJA": No address associated with hostname
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
W/System.err:     at com.example.hostname.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(MainActivity.java:42)
W/System.err:     at com.example.hostname.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:202)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:73)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:135)
W/System.err:   ... 5 more
```

The same program works well on laptops but throws error in when ran in android (physical device not emulator)

note: Android manifest contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: What O/S do the laptops run?  How is your DNS setup?  At a guess you've got a Microsoft environment and Windows is hiding some of the complexity of the network domain.

Comment: It is running windows 11 and I don't have any specific DNS setup

Comment: Have you found cause for that? Not sure if my problem is similar, but I'm getting similar exception only when using cellular network. On WiFi all connection are working correctly..